# Spiral generation loop

Tags: java

Not a while ago I asked this in the game dev forums:

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/35573/how-do-i-efficiently-generate-chunks-to-fill-entire-screen-when-my-player-moves/35575#comment59944_35575

I got an answer to make spiral generation. I went ahead and implemented this:

```
Chunk c = null;
for (int j = 1;j< 4;j++) {
    for (int k =0;k<4;k++) {
        c = this.checkChunksToLoad(k, j*8);
    }
        c = c.getAdjacentChunk(3);
}
```

checkChunksToLoad takes in a direction and the other number is how far the chunk you are looking for is from the player. 8 means 8 tiles or 1 chunk 16 would be 2 chunks away from the player's chunk and so on. This method once finds the required chunk generates it and returns it to an object if you would like to mess with it.

and get adjacent chunk method takes in a direction and gives you the adjacent chunk in that direction.

Directions:

0 = up 1 = left 2 = right 3 = down

The code posted above only gives me in the four directions chunks but the space between them is not generated. How would I do so?

Basically it should spirally generate 3 by 3 Chunks of space around the player.

this == player class

Comment: If any more information is need tell me..

Comment: I'm still not 100% clear on what you're after here. Perhaps give a more comprehensive explanation? Usually, annotated code with an explanation at each step is helpful in conveying meaning.